# Show an Image in applicationWillResignActive in Swift 5

Tags: swift, flutter, swift5

So, I'm trying to show an image on the recent screen when the app goes to the background. I have achieved a blur effect, but I want to replace the blur with an image of custom background white color. I'm not sure, where to add the image in the project and how to use it.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  let TAG_BLUR_VIEW = 12345
  var blurView:UIVisualEffectView?
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  override func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let view = self.window.rootViewController?.view.subviews.first(where: {$0.tag == TAG_BLUR_VIEW}){
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        blurView = nil
    }
    if blurView == nil{
        blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        blurView?.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        blurView?.tag = TAG_BLUR_VIEW
    }
    self.window.rootViewController?.view.insertSubview(blurView!, at: 0)

  }


override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let view = self.window.rootViewController?.view.subviews.first(where: {$0.tag == TAG_BLUR_VIEW}){
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        blurView = nil
    }
  
}
}
```

FYI: This is a flutter project, I'm going native for this feature. So total swift newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  // this tag can be any number. This tag will get assingned to the blurView, 
  // This tag will be used to removed the blur, when the app is in foreground.
  let TAG_BLUR_VIEW = 12345
  var blurView:UIImageView?
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  override func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
   let centerPos = self.window?.rootViewController?.view.center ?? .zero
   if let view = self.window.rootViewController?.view.subviews.first(where: {$0.tag == TAG_BLUR_VIEW}){
       view.removeFromSuperview()
       blurView = nil
   }
    if blurView == nil{
        blurView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "secure.jpg")) //replace your image
        blurView?.backgroundColor = UIColor .white
        blurView?.tag = TAG_BLUR_VIEW
        blurView?.center = centerPos
    }
    // The bulr screen with the tag "12345" is added to the index 0
    self.window.rootViewController?.view.insertSubview(blurView!, at: 0)

  }

  // if the tag on the index 0, matches our blur tag, it removes the blur once the app is on foreground.
  override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if let view = self.window.rootViewController?.view.subviews.first(where: {$0.tag == TAG_BLUR_VIEW}){
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        blurView = nil
    }
  
}
}
```